# displaying query result as default item in a datagridview combo box

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview, combobox

I have a query that loads data from a MySQL db into a datagridview but in that same datagridview I have a combobox. The items list is being populated from another query. When the user first saves the data, he selects an item from the combobox and fills in the other columns by hand. The row is then saved with an insert query. What I want to do is display what was previously saved in the datagridview including the combobox choice. How do I go about showing the list item that was previously saved as the default item in the combobox?

here is the save code:

```
public void SaveOperations()
    {
        // create new row in project_operations with datagridview operations
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"insert into shopmanager.project_operations (products_product_id, operation_name, operation_description) values (@products_product_id, @operation_name, @operation_description)", con);
        con.Open();


        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in operation_dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            try
            {
                if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@products_product_id", product_id.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation_name", row.Cells["combo"].Value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation_description", row.Cells["Description"].Value);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Operation Sauvegardé");
        con.Close();
    }
```

Here is the load code. This loads the data to the other cells in the row apart from the combobox. When I try to load the operation_name, it's creates a new column but what I want is for the operation name to be in the combobox. How can I achieve that?

```
private void LoadData()
    {
        // fill textbox columns
        MessageBox.Show("load operations data textboxes");
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"select operation_description as 'Description', operation_start_date as 'Début', operation_finish_date as 'Fin', users_employee_number as 'Employé' from shopmanager.project_operations where products_product_id = @product_id", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", product_id.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];

            operation_dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think after setting the dataSource, I'll do like below (for both combo or check):

```
//ADD COLUMNS
var comboBox = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboBox.HeaderText = "Header title";
comboBox.Name = "combo box";

var dataRow = new ArrayList();

foreach(var dr in dt.Rows)
   dataRow.Add(dr["fieldName"].ToString()); // this will be the combo box data from database

// add data to combobox
comboBox.Items.AddRange(dataRow.ToArray());

// finally add the combo box to dgv
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(comboBox);

}
```